# My code keeps saying, "Attribute Error: 'int' has no attribute 'append'." How do I fix this?

Tags: list, append, attributeerror

My project is to create a while loop asking the user to enter numbers. Then, they are to add them to the list:

```
nums = 0
limit = 0
my_list = [ ]
while limit < 11:
    nums= int(input("Enter a number: "))
    nums.append(nums)

    if nums == 0:
        break
```

Comment: Well, as it says: num (which is an integer) doesn't have a method append. In other words your code is wrong. Maybe append/push it to my_list and not nums?

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list.append(nums);
```

`nums` is an integer. It doesn't have methods.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out last night.